# ExtJs 5.1.3 datefield getValue plus one day

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, datefield

My problem is : I want to select startDate ("from") date in datefield, by default i can select from tomorrow as minimum if i select 20july for example, i want that my endDate field ("to") as minValue 21july and invert thing, if i select endDate at first for example 27july, maxValue for startDate is 26july, i've tried this

```
listeners: {
    change: function(item, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
        var fieldSet = item.up('fieldset');
        var cmpDateFrom = Ext.getCmp('userAffectDateFieldStart');
        var cmpDateEnd = Ext.getCmp('userAffectDateFieldEnd');
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1);
        if((!cmpDateFrom && !cmpDateEnd) && newValue.user_affect === 'temp'){
            fieldSet.insert(
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    id: 'userAffectDateFieldStart',
                    fieldLabel: 'A partir de :',
                    name: 'user_affect_from',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    minValue: tomorrow,
                    maskRe: /[0-9\/]/,
                    startDay: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(el){
                            var elValue = el.getValue();
                            var elValuePlusOne = Ext.Date.add(elValue,Ext.Date.DAY,1);
                            var endDateEl = Ext.getCmp('userAffectDateFieldEnd');

                            console.dir(elValue);
                            console.dir(elValuePlusOne);

                            if(elValue !== null) endDateEl.setMinValue(elValue);
                            if(elValue === null) endDateEl.setMinValue(tomorrow);
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    id: 'userAffectDateFieldEnd',
                    fieldLabel: 'Jusqu\' au :',
                    name: 'user_affect_to',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    minValue: tomorrow,
                    maskRe: /[0-9\/]/,
                    startDay: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(el){
                            var elValue = el.getValue();
                            var elValueMinusOne = Ext.Date.add(elValue,Ext.Date.DAY,-1);
                            var startDateEl = Ext.getCmp('userAffectDateFieldStart');

                            if(elValue !== null) startDateEl.setMaxValue(elValue);
                            if(elValue === null) startDateEl.setMinValue(tomorrow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            fieldSet.doLayout();
        } else {
            fieldSet.remove(cmpDateFrom, true);
            fieldSet.remove(cmpDateEnd, true);
        }
    }
}
```

But i have this error message "**Uncaught TypeError: date.getTime is not a function**"
And "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTime')**"

When i erase startDate, endDate minValue stay at oldStartDateDay plus one day.

Comment: Please, add actual code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @aca , hello, it's done ;)

Comment: There is a good example in KitchenSink that shows you how to do it using Custom VTypes: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-advtypes